# pip won't install Python packages locally with --user

Tags: python, package, pip, easy-install, pythonpath

I'm trying to install packages locally with pip. It used to work with `--user` but now when I try it, it finds the version of the package in `/usr/local/lib/` and then does not install it locally. Normally it would install things in `~/.local` but now it just checks the system-wide dir for the package and if it's there, it does not install it (which is not what I want) and if it's not there, it tries to install it in `/usr/local/lib` which I do not have write permissions at. Eg:

```
$ pip install --user rpy2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): rpy2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

How can I make `pip install --user` always go to `~/.local` and not a system-wide directory?

Comment: well it says that the it "Requirement" is satisfied and it tells you to use the --upgrade option, have you tried using it?

Comment: @PurityLake: yes, that doesn't change anything

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers", like `pip`, are on topic. Voted to reopen.

Comment: I agree this should be reopened. A similar question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269101/using-pip-to-install-packages-locally-in-spite-of-satisfied-global-requirements?rq=1

Comment: This may not be a fix, but this could save you some time. Try to use virtualenv where you want an installation different from system wide installation

Comment: I think my answer provides solution – could you please check it out?

Answer (score 23):

[Citing](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/766#issuecomment-29544589) Marcus Smith (maintainer of pip):

> If you think the global site is out of date, and want the latest in
>   the user site, then use:
>   `pip install --upgrade --user SomePackage`
>
> If the global site is up to date, and you really just want the same
>   thing duplicated in `--user`, then use:
>   `pip install --ignore-installed --user SomePackage` (which works correctly now after the merge of #1352, which is to be released in v1.5)

*How can I make `pip install --user` always go to `~/.local` and not a system-wide directory?*

Use both `--upgrade` and `--ignore-installed` arguments.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning pip bugs. The only thing I'm missing is to combine --prefix with --user, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420125/python-change-user-site-directory-or-install-setup-py-prefix-with-user

Answer (score 4):

According to the pip documentation, that syntax is correct, but requires Python 2.6.

> **User Installs**
>
> With Python 2.6 came the “user scheme” for installation, which means
>   that all Python distributions support an alternative install location
>   that is specific to a user. The default location for each OS is
>   explained in the python documentation for the site.USER_BASE variable.
>   This mode of installation can be turned on by specifying the –user
>   option to pip install.
>
> Moreover, the “user scheme” can be customized by setting the
>   PYTHONUSERBASE environment variable, which updates the value of
>   site.USER_BASE.
>
> To install “SomePackage” into an environment with site.USER_BASE
>   customized to ‘/myappenv’, do the following:

```
export PYTHONUSERBASE=/myappenv 
pip install --user SomePackage
```

So the following entry should work for you:

```
export PYTHONUSERBASE=~/.local
pip install --user rpy2
```

Comment: The pip documentation is located at:  [pip cookbook](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/cookbook.html)

Comment: MagicalPony: Did not know about that, thanks. But setting PYTHONUSERBASE does not work - it's still looking in `/usr/local/lib/`

Comment: `pip install --user --force-reinstall --upgrade jinja2` can install to `~/.local/` dir.

Comment: This may not be a fix, but this could save you some time. Try to use virtualenv where you want an installation different from system wide installation

Answer (score 0):

[installing any package using user command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhMGJ.png)

for upgrading pip :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --user pip
```