# using pip to install packages locally in spite of satisfied global requirements

Tags: python, numpy, pip, setuptools, pythonpath

I am trying to use pip to install a package locally in `~/.local`. The problem is that the package (in an older version) is already available globally on the system. Even though the global python packages directory is *not* in my `PYTHONPATH`, pip still refuses to install, thinking that the package requirement is satisfied. This is similar to the issue described here, except I am not using `sudo` so the solution does not apply: [pip - Requirement already satisfied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665330/pip-requirement-already-satisfied)

If I do:

```
pip install --user numpy
```

It says:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.6.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
```

However, `/usr/local/lib/...` is not in my `PYTHONPATH`. The only thing in `PYTHONPATH` is `~/.local`.

If I try to do:

```
pip install --user --upgrade numpy
```

It downloads numpy and compiles it, and then thinks I am doing a global install **in spite of the --user** flag and I get:

```
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.6.2
    Uninstalling numpy:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 107, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 261, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1162, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 495, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1492, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 273, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 300, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/f2py'
```

How can this be fixed? I'm not sure why it tries to do anything that requires global permissions when it's passed the `--user` flag.

Is there a way to tell pip to just use `~/.local` and ignore everything else on the system? (I don't want to use virtualenv!  It's unnecessary here, I don't want multiple environments, just one.)

Comment: why wouldn't you use `virtualenv`, isn't this the Exact reason it was created?

Comment: Numpy is not playing well with pip. It is trying to install `f2py` on `/usr/bin/`. Probably because it is outside python's `site-packages`. Most likely there will be other files that have to be installed outside of that, and pip doesn't seem to know how to deal with it. Not sure if virtualenv will help here.

Comment: @tiago *Numpy is not playing well with pip. It is trying to install f2py on /usr/bin/.* No, it does not. It's pip trying to **uninstall** system numpy which fails due to lack of permissions. See my answer.

Comment: I think my answer provides solution – could you please check it out?

Answer (score 2):

[Citing](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/766#issuecomment-29544589) Marcus Smith (maintainer of pip):

> If you think the global site is out of date, and want the latest in
>   the user site, then use:
>   `pip install --upgrade --user SomePackage`

Because *(...) the package (in an older version) is already available globally on the system* you have to use `--upgrade` option as per above Marcus' remark.
Uninstalling system numpy package is probably a bug in the version of pip you use (1.2.1). Try current version as many issues related to `--user` option were fixed in versions 1.3 and 1.4

EDIT

Marcus Smith [points](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/766#issuecomment-29559162) to specific issue in his later comment:

> pip 1.3 has #705 , which is critical for using --user and --upgrade
>   together.