# python, change user site directory or install setup.py --prefix with --user

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, pythonpath

I'd want to install python modules as non-root user like this

```
$ pip install -I --install-option="--prefix=~/usr" scipy
```

Unfortunately this usually does not work unless you specify `--user`. But `--user` can't be used together with `--prefix`. Using `--user` only (without `--prefix`) installs to `~/.local` which I find ugly because I have a well maintained `~/usr` and don't want to add even more stuff to my `env` to make `~/.local` usable too.

So my questions:

1. How can I let `--prefix` and `--user` work together for setup.py or how else could setup.py succeed without using `--user`?
2. Or can I change the user site directory from `~/.local` to `~/usr` somehow by `env`?

Comment: I don't see why `--install-option="--prefix=~/usr"` shouldn't work. Please tell us what error you get.

Comment: For me --prefix works only if it's not installed globally already. It tries to uninstall the global module and aborts with error. Can I disable "uninstall" somehow? --ignore-installed is not enough.

Comment: I guess `--ignore-installed` is not compatible with `--install-option="--prefix=..."` as the former is pip's option while the latter is being passed directly to setuptools. You could try to use pip's `--target` option which should prevent pip from trying to uninstall system wide package.

Comment: --target does not work neither. I had also tried a lot directly with setup.py to avoid any odd behavior of pip. (Note that there are some related bugs in pip <1.5.) Anyway, PYTHONUSERBASE is a good workaround, although --prefix should IMO simply do the same what we already know from "./configure --prefix ... && make install".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your first question:

In [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/install/) guide written by Greg Ward we read:

> Note that the various alternate installation schemes are mutually
>   exclusive: you can pass --user, or --home, or --prefix and
>   --exec-prefix, or --install-base and --install-platbase, but you can’t mix from these groups.

To answer your second question:

In the same guide there's section [Alternate installation: the user scheme](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme) where we read:

> Files will be installed into subdirectories of `site.USER_BASE`

with `site.USER_BASE` linked to https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE. There we are asked to see also information on [`PYTHONUSERBASE`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUSERBASE) environment variable:

> Defines the user base directory, which is used to compute the path of
>   the user site-packages directory and Distutils installation paths for
>   python setup.py install --user.

Also, you might be interested in [the home scheme](https://docs.python.org/2.7/install/#alternate-installation-the-home-scheme):

> The idea behind the “home scheme” is that you build and maintain a
>   personal stash of Python modules. This scheme’s name is derived from
>   the idea of a “home” directory on Unix, since it’s not unusual for a
>   Unix user to make their home directory have a layout similar to /usr/
>   or /usr/local/.

Comment: Thanks! PYTHONUSERBASE env solves my issue. Unfortunately it was not mentioned in the man page.

Comment: @rudimeier: Right, man python mentions PYTHONNOUSERBASE but not PYTHONUSERBASE.  Would you mind reporting this on bugs.python.org?

Comment: Do you really have PYTHONNOUSERBASE in man page? I have only PYTHONNOUSERSITE (option -s). Is *USERBASE another different thing than *USERSITE?  I'm going to bug report it.

Comment: I mistyped, it’s indeed PYTHONNOUSERSITE.

(The USERBASE envvar/option/variable is the base used to define USERSITE and other directories like the scripts dir.)

Comment: wtf are there env variables we can set or..? As only an occassional user of python, I don't know what `site.USER_BASE` refers to.