# Can't install requirements using pip and python 3.8.5 on a Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip

I'm trying to install python dependencies for a Django project, but I keep getting `Non-user install because user site-packages disabled` error. It sounds like a permission issue, I just can't figure out what went wrong. My working tools include:

1. Django
2. Python 3.8.5
3. Ubuntu 20.04

Probably worth mentioning, I am using a virtual environment for this project. Also, I have tried using root to install the packages without any luck. Any ideas on how to solve this issue is more than welcome.

Comment: do you have the venv activated? How did you create the venv?
take a look at the comments in this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420125/python-change-user-site-directory-or-install-setup-py-prefix-with-user

Comment: Yep, virtual env is activated. I used `python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment` to create my virtual environment.

Comment: In that question I posted in my previous comment there is an answer, see if that and/or the comments to that answer are helpful. I never come across that problem.

Comment: Which package installation is causing the problem?

Comment: is this a deployment on a service provider or on your local computer ? 
Some service providers offer very limited resources in Python and prevent any new packages to be installed.

Comment: @Razenstein It happens when I try to install a requirements file with multiple packages. If I install one package, I don't see the issue, which is weird.

Comment: @FabriceJaouën I am deploying to AWS, I was running the command using Ansible, but I have tried sshing to the server and running the command manually, same issue

Comment: I would debug it the "stupid" way: put 1 item in requirements then 2 ... 4 ... and see when it fails

Comment: It depends really on your provider and your billing plan: OVH is weird and nothing is clear (their core business is obviously either people on PHP or medium/large companies, AWS offers a bunch of plans with different options. Frankly, the only one I could find, which runs smoothly on Python and where everything is clearly and simply explained with up-to-date tutorials remains DigitalOcean.